# "Post Your Example Question" button becomes inactive if I post a new question too early

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, example-questions

On Area51 I open a proposal, go to the page bottom and enter a question into the form, then press "Post Your Example Question" button - the question is posted. Then I enter another question there and post the button again - the text appears

> new users can only post example questions every 3 minutes; try again later.

and the "Post Your Example Question" button gets inactive forever. So when the three minutes pass clicking on the button has no effect until I put the cursor into the form edit - only then the button gets active again and I can post the question.

Comment: The button is only active if you focus on the text box and then press it.